# How can I import a package from within the same package?

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-import

I got this python package here called "pgk", and I'd like to import it from a module within itself:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty

`test.py`:

- When trying `from .. import pkg`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Game Dev\pkg\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import pkg
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

- When trying `import pkg`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Game Dev\pkg\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'
```

I read a lot about the import system in Python 3 and usually get around issues like this one, but this time it all failed. I even tried messing around with sys.path amongst other stuff, but I just can't figure out how I can achieve this.

Comment: How are you executing `test.py`? I.E what is the working directory when you do so?

Comment: Hi DeepSpace, I run the module test.py with IDLE, cwd is `C:\Game Dev\pkg`

Answer (score 0):

I see there is only one file in the dir (expept the init). Did you try to import test.py?

Comment: Hi Nikoi, I open test.py in IDLE and run it. I'd like to import pkg in test.py.

Comment: Did you try to import a single module from pkg? If modules are in the same dir as test.py, you can use from pkg import some_module, otherwise, you can import them using sys: ```import sys 
sys.path.append('/path/to/pkg')
from pkg import some_module```

Comment: I'd like to access and use the whole pkg from within test.py, not single modules from the package. Perhaps I should reformulate my question since It seems rather unclear: The goal is that I have a package (a game engine). Inside this package, I would like a module that is used to showcase the engine. When executing the test.py module, tests are run to showcase what the package can do, so it needs to be imported inside test.py.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I meant if you tried to run/access anything from the package? Did you try putting test.py in a different subfolder and try importing the package? Did you try sys approach like so: ```import sys  sys.path.append('/path/to/pkg') import pkg``` ?